# AS3 Facebook App - album photos size

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, facebook, graph

I'm developing a facebook app using the new AS3 facebook graph api (1.5).

The app grabs the facebook users photo albums and displays them in a flash tilelist component.

Right now I'm grabbing the album photo urls via an fql query for 'src_big'.

Feeding these images into a tilelist, the major problem is that portrait images don't fill the tile.

If you look at any facebook photo album, all the photos, landscape and portrait, are fitted into a landscape shaped box (which appears to be 211x157 pixels from a quick screengrab I've done).

Does any expert know how to call "that" landscape cropped image into Flash via the flash facebook graph api? Is there some fql query, or other method?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the different sizes that FB offers for pictures?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo

Click on the "example link" inside that page and see if any format matches what you are looking for.